# two lines / line break in li element

Tags: html, html-lists

I have a `<ul>` with a couple of `<li>`. In my css with `li { display: inline; }` I put the li elements in a horizontal order. The li elements contain a picutre and text. But now the picture and the text are also in horizontal order, but I want them to be under neeth each other. How can I do that?

```
<ul>
        <li>

                <img src="img/a.png" />
                A

        </li>
        <li>

                <img src="img/b.png" />
                B

        </li>
        <li>

                <img src="img/c.png"/>
                C

        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Why dont you use `<br/>` ?

Comment: Just add display:block om image

Comment: @Lal > While I use it too because I find it easier, it is important to note the `<br />` tag isn't semantic...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to change your CSS as follows:

```
li { 
  display: inline-block; 
}

li img {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is a quick demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLLoEZ

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug but a normal behaviour. `<img>` tag is by default inline. You could solve this non-issue by either wrapping either your image or, better, your text into a block element. For example, a `<p>`tag for your text :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100" />
        <p>Your text here</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100" />
        <p>Your text here</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100" />
        <p>Your text here</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cy0rmydn/)

Note I use `display:inline-block` on li elements, taking advantage of both `inline` (putting things side-by-side, alignment,...) and `block` (fixed size, top/bottom margins) properties. Although it has [a strange but easilly fixed](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) "feature/issue", this is most of the time the best way to put elements side-by-side. `display: inline` or floating elements are also used but come with some other issues sometimes a bit trickier to be fixed.